# T2i Shutter not operating properly in manual mode

Tags: canon, shutter

I have taken thousands of pictures on my seven-year-old Canon T2i with no issues. Then, out of the blue, I am finding that when the camera is in manual, T, AV, P or A-DEP mode, I have to press the shutter release button twice for the camera to take a picture. I've checked all the settings; nothing corrects it. It doesn't do this in any of the auto modes.  Is it possible I've accidentally changed some bizarre setting that I can't find? I don't know.

And it's not as though the shutter is open the whole time between clicks. It makes a sound, and you can tell it's not operating correctly. also, the viewfinder is black while your press the shutter release the second time.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have managed to enable *Mirror Lockup*. The reason you aren't experiencing this in any of the 'Auto' modes is that *Mirror Lockup* is not available in the 'Auto' modes. It is only available in the creative exposure modes: **P/Tv/Av/M/A-DEP**

To turn off *Mirror Lockup*, go to [Menu → Set-Up 3 (the third yellow wrench tab) → Custom Functions (C.Fn) → C.Fn III: Autofocus/Drive → C.Fn-8 Mirror Lockup] and select **0: Disable**.

[Mirror Lockup](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/63696/15871) is explained on page 106 of the [*EOS Rebel T2i/EOS 550D Instruction Manual*](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/9/0300004289/02/eosrt2i-eos550d-im3-c-en.pdf)

[image: p. 106]