# Why does my Canon 600D take pictures in live mode but not in viewfinder mode?

Tags: canon, viewfinder, canon-600d, live-view, shutter-release

My Canon 600D takes pictures in live mode, but when I switch to the viewfinder and press the shutter button it can't take pictures...it gets completely blank...the camera is blocked..and when I click on the shutter button again, it goes to normal position. Can anyone tell me how to make this work?

Comment: Have you verified that the mirror is lifting correctly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like you have [mirror lockup](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/1593/15871) enabled. The first full press of the shutter button will cause the mirror to move up (just as it does before taking a normal photo using the viewfinder) but the shutter will not be opened. A *second* full press of the shutter button will activate the shutter to take the photo. If the shutter is not pressed again for 30 seconds after the first press that locks up the mirror, the camera will automatically release the mirror back down to its normal resting position without taking a photo.

Set your dial to TV, AV, M - Anything other than Fully Automatic Exposure modes, otherwise this will not work.

- Go in to Custom Function III : Autofocus/Drive
- Scroll to Screen 8 - Mirror Lockup
- Select 0:Disable

This should release the mirror.

If it doesn’t, you may need to hard reset the camera.
That is to remove the Battery and the internal clock Battery and leave it over night.
Once the power goes back on, it generally resets minor malfunctions.